# WhereIn en laravel con resultados en null

Tags: laravel

cuando hago la consulta me regresa la consulta vacía y si solo hago un solo filtro me trae los resultados

```
Coupon::whereIn('project_id',[$projectId, 'IS NULL'])
            ->where('customer_id',$customerId)
            ->get();
```

Comment: quiero traer los cupones que estén para ese proyecto y que sean en general para todos cuando es para todos el campo es nulo o sino solo se puede aplicar el id eso se trata la consulta además tiene que pertenecer a un cliente  esas son las dos clausuras que se tienen que cumplir

Comment: este seria el sql SELECT * FROM coupons where (project_id = 1 or project_id IS NULL) and customer_id = 1 and unit_id IS NULL and deleted_at IS NULL;

Comment: la consulta en sql si funciona bien y la queri en este momento de laravel no me devuelve nada cuando hay ya me debería mandas resultados pero no devuelve nada la consulta completa en laravel seria $coupons = Coupon::whereIn('project_id',[$projectId, 'IS NULL'])
   ->where('customer_id' , $customerId)
   ->whereIn('coupon_type' , [2,1])
   ->whereNull('unit_id')
   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
   ->get();

Comment: `código`$coupons = Coupon::whereIn('project_id',[$projectId, 'IS NULL'])
   ->where('customer_id' , $customerId)
   ->whereIn('coupon_type' , [2,1])
   ->whereNull('unit_id')
   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
   ->get();

Comment: también intente con este código y nada $coupons = Coupon::whereRaw('project_id = '.$projectId.' or project_id IS NULL')
   ->where('customer_id' , $customerId)
   ->whereIn('coupon_type' , [2,1])
   ->whereNull('unit_id')
   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
   ->get();

Comment: Por favor coloca en tu pregunta todo intento realizado mediante la edición de la misma, posterior puedes eliminar los comentarios :)

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo siguiente:

- Cuando colocas: **`whereIn('columna', ['valor1', 'IS NULL'])`** estarías indicando que en el segundo argumento (*el array*) el segundo valor es un string con un valor de **IS NULL** lo cual desde luego es incorrecto (*para la consulta que planeas desarrollar*).
- Lo que puedes hacer es emplear el método [whereNull](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) para precisamente evaluar si el valor de una columna determinada esta como NULL
- Ahora como la primera pareja de condiciones a evaluar quedan agrupadas entonces conviene que pases ambas dentro de un [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping)

Entonces tu consulta puede quedar de esta forma:

```
Coupon::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('project_id', 1)
        ->orWhereNull('project_id');
})->where('customer_id', 1)
->whereNull('unit_id')
->whereNull('deleted_at')
->get();
```